# ssh passwdless failed after add id_rsa.pub to remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh

My remote machine has 2 users one is `root` and another is `Alexander`. And I create a new user `fit` with `root` user.

```
# adduser fit
```

And I `scp` the `id_rsa.pub` of my home machine to `fit@remote_machine` and add to the authorized_keys.

```
fit$ cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

But, after that I still have to input the passwd to login remote machine

```
home$ ssh fit@remote_machine
fit@remote_machine's password: 
Last login: Fri Apr 15 09:55:34 2016
fit@localhost.localdomain:[/home/fit]
```

But, what really made me puzzled is that I `scp` the `id_rsa.pub` of my home machine to `Alexander@remote_machine`, and add to the `authorized_keys` of `Alexander@remote_machine`. And I can login the remote machine without passwd:

```
home$ ssh alexander@remote_machine # login without passwd
Last login: Fri Apr 15 09:58:19 2016 from 27.46.137.183
/etc/profile:fc:80: no such event: 1
Alexander@localhost: ~
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have the correct permissions set on fit's ~/.ssh folder and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file? 700 the former, 600 the latter.

Comment: @mjt, yes, right, after `chmod`, the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

It was the permissions that made ssh passwdless connected failed. Change the permissions

```
$ chmod 700 .ssh
$ chmod 600 authorized_keys
```

Now, it works fine.